# App Inventor 2: Not finding a specific block

Tags: bluetooth, app-inventor

In the App Inventor 2, where is the block mentioned in last item (figure) of the url: http://beta.appinventor.mit.edu/learn/reference/blocks/definition.html

I am trying to use bluetooth to connect my custom device with Android App.

The internet says:

> This block provides a "dummy socket" for fitting a block that has a
>   plug on its left into a place where there is no socket, such as one of
>   the sequence of blocks in the do part of a procedure or an if block.
>   The block you fit in will be run, but its returned result will be
>   ignored. This can be useful if you define a procedure that returns a
>   result, but want to call it in a context that does not accept a
>   result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the [**evaluate but ignore result**](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/support/blocks/control.html#evaluate) block
[image]

However in your bluetooth connecting example let me recommend you to use an if statement instead

> if BluetoothClient1.connect ... 
>   then do something
>   else display a message, e.g. "connection was not successful"

see also [this bluetooth example](http://puravidaapps.com/btchat.php)
and see the [documentation of the Bluetooth components](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/connectivity.html#BluetoothClient)

> boolean Connect(text address)
>       Connect to the Bluetooth device with the specified address and the Serial Port Profile (SPP).
>   **Returns true if the connection was successful.**